# Remove icon from notification panel in Ubuntu MATE

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-mate, notification-area

[image: icon]

How can I remove these icons from Ubuntu MATE notification area? On right click it shows nothing to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is MATE keyboard LEDs indicator.

You can remove it from MATE Tweak:

1. Start it by *System->Preferences->Look and Feel->MATE Tweak* or `mate-tweak`.
2. Switch to *Interface* tab.
3. In *Panel Features* uncheck *Enable keyboard LED*.