# Visual indication for special keys

Tags: keyboard, indicator, gnome-shell

Is there some command, or app, to show a visual indication about the state of special keys (Caps Lock, Num Lock, etc)?

It is intended to be used with some keyboards without the "standard" indicator leds.

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.1 and Gnome desktop enviroment.

Comment: About MATE see this thread - https://askubuntu.com/q/1009218/66509 .

Comment: I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.1 and Gnome desktop enviroment.

Comment: I tried the solution shows in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067740/capslock-indicator-for-ubuntu-18-04 but... Even the fact that my system tells me that gnome-tweak-tool is installed, I can not to run it. Not from a Terminal, Not from the "Run software...". This is not the only native Gnome enviroment command that doesn't work into UbuntuStudio. I guess there is something missed or blocked. I don't have any clue about that, but...

Comment: @Juan Are you **sure** you have GNOME? If I'm not mistaken Ubuntu Studio has Xfce by default, **not** GNOME. You're most probably not running GNOME if you haven't installed it manually. Please clarify.

Comment: I installed all I found about Gnome (I used Synaptic). The computer desktop looks like Gnome! But... There are a lot of things that still don't work or don't appear here! I guess I don't have enough computing world skills to fix this! Sorry!