# Key-indicator on ubuntu desktop

Tags: 16.04, editor

My laptop keyboard does not indicate Caps key/Num key. So I installed indicator-keylock. Now, how to use it? It is not indicating any key operations.

Comment: According to: https://www.howtogeek.com/274587/how-to-get-a-notification-when-caps-lock-or-num-lock-is-enabled-in-ubuntu/ you need to reboot after installation. Or at least log out and in again.

Comment: Also for MATE DE you can use *Enable keyboard LED* (see [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/1009218/66509)).